# How can I import a .csv into multiple arrays in a simpler way?

Tags: arrays, powershell, import

I am new to powershell and am writing my first somewhat complicated script.  I would like to import a .csv file and create multiple text arrays with it.  I think that I have found a way that will work but it will be time consuming to generate all of the lines that I need.  I assume I can do it more simply using foreach-object but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

See my current code...

```
$vmimport = Import-Csv "gss_prod.csv"
$gssall = $vmimport | ForEach-Object {$_.vmName}`
$gssweb = $vmimport | Where-Object {$_.tier -eq web} | ForEach-Object {$_.vmName}
$gssapp = $vmimport | Where-Object {$_.tier -eq app} | ForEach-Object {$_.vmName}
$gsssql = $vmimport | Where-Object {$_.tier -eq sql} | ForEach-Object {$_.vmName}
```

The goal is to make 1 group with all entries containing only the vmName value, and then 3 separate groups containing only the vmName value but using the tier value to sort them.

Can anyone help me with an easier way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed that I do have an unrelated mistake here...  the last three lines say $gssall when they should say $vmimport.  That isn't the issue I am having.

Comment: You can edit your question... and maybe explain why your current code doesn't work the way you want it.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would need to do this? What is wrong with the collection as it is?

Comment: Nothing is WRONG per se, I am just trying to learn how to do things more efficiently.  This is eventually going to be a 60-70 category code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the last three you can group the object by the Tier property and have the result as a hasthable. Then you can reference the Tier name to get its VMs.

```
#group objects by tier
$gs = $vmimport | Group-Object tier -AsHashTable

# get web VMs
$gs['web']

# get sql VMs
$gs['app']
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a dictionary for storing the data:

```
$vmimport = Import-Csv "gss_prod.csv"

$gssall = $vmimport | % { $_.vmName }

$categories = "web", "app", "sql", ...
$gss = @{}
foreach ($cat in $categories) {
  $gss[$cat] = $vmimport | ? { $_.tier -eq $cat } | % { $_.vmName }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the Shay Levy way, but the values of hash tables remain hash tables. Here is an other more efficient approach where values are jagged arrays, and categories are made automatically (contrary to Ansgar Wiechers solution):

```
# define hashtable
$gs = @{};

# fill it
$vmimport | foreach {$gs[$_.tier]+=, $_.vmName};

# get web VMs
$gs['web'] # the result is an array of 'web' vmNames.
```